# Duplicate events user logon on winlogbeat using drop event filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Here is the scenario:
When I successfully log into my lab computer, the event ID 4672 duplicates the Administrator users.

[image]

This works well, but what I can't find out how to do, is to remove the duplicate events from event ID 4672 and 4624

```
proccessors:
- drop_event.when.or:
      - equals.winlog.event_id: 4624
      - equals.event_data.LogonType: '0'
      - equals.event_data.LogonType: '5'
      - equals.winlog.event_data.SubjectUserSid: 'S-1-5-18'
      - equals.winlog.event_data.SubjectUserSid: 'S-1-0-0'
      - equals.winlog.event_data.TargetUserName: 'SYSTEM'
```